# How do I find out install4j's default for the countersigning URL?

Tags: install4j

Using `org.sonatype.install4j:install4j-maven-plugin:1.1.1:compile` with install4j7.
It is failing with `install4j: compilation failed. Reason: error during counter signing: java.io.IOException: connect timed out`.
This is most likely firewalls blocking the build server from reaching the counter signing server, but how do I make install4j log the URL is was trying to use? (Maven's debug logging didn't help.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer in https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/install4j.pdf:

install4j uses the DigiCert time stamp signing service at

`http://timestamp.digicert.com`

and falls back to the GlobalSign time stamp signing service at

`http://timestamp.globalsign.com`

if there is a failure.